# Rename file with a string within the file

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I have a file named `psgl_extract.txt` that I want renamed with the string within the file.
The string `AURNTRNA20170509V141` is located in the first row of the file.
Both batch file and target file will be in the same directory, d:\abc

Extract from file:

```
00AURNTRNA20170509V141

01RNET           201705090010020030000  7158254                                               562009    AUD-00000000000000000000000.020                                                                                   200300009502015 03955711000283
01RNET           201705090010020030000  2347394
```

Desired Output:

```
AURNTRNA.20170509.V141.txt
```

Comment: Does the first row only contain the string and nothing more always? You only need to get the string from line one so is it safe to assume line one will always only contain the string which you want the file name to be and nothing more, correct?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is Correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a lot of work to rename just one file! Can you not open it copy the first line close it and rename with an edited paste.

That said here are some solutions using assumed information regarding the structure you have provided:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "D:\abc\psgl_extract.txt" GoTo :EOF
Set/P "_S="<"D:\abc\psgl_extract.txt"
For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=0123456789" %%A In ("%_S%") Do (Set "_A=%%A"
    For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ('Call Echo^=%%_S:*%%A^=%%') Do Set "_N=%%B")
Ren "D:\abc\psgl_extract.txt" "%_A%.%_N:~,8%.%_N:~8%.txt"
```

If there are several .txt files in the same directory **all** with the same assumed structure then you may be able to use this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%A In (*.txt) Do (
    Set/P "_S="<"%%A"
    For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=0123456789" %%B In ("!_S!") Do (Set "_A=%%B"
        For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In ('Echo^=!_S:*%%B^=!') Do Set "_N=%%C")
    Ren "%%A" "!_A!.!_N:~,8!.!_N:~8!%%~xA")
```